# NodeJS & Express - esc is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is the exact error message I'm getting:

TypeError: /Users/benjidurden/Desktop/page-plant-bonham-jones/views/index.ejs:24

```
22| <div class="spacing"></div>
23| <div class="content">
24| <%- include ./partials/loops %>
25| </div>
26|  <%- include ./partials/scripts %>
27|   </body>
```

esc is not a function
    at rethrow

(/Users/benjidurden/Desktop/page-plant-bonham-jones/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:285:18)

Below shows the content of the loops.ejs; the following loop exists inside. Essentially, I was trying to generate a forEach loop that places all of the content inside of this div. Regardless, I don't know how to fix this mistake. Any advice?

```
<ul>
<% data.forEach(function(d) { %>
<li data-id=<%=d.id%>>
<input class="input_item" type="text" name="first" 
        placeholder=<%= d.album %> readonly>
      <span class="edit">edit</span>
      <span class="delete">delete</span>
    </li> 
   <% }) %>
</ul>
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42699580/nodejs-esc-is-not-a-function/42707145

Comment: @jonathandion i saw that response, but i'm not entirely sure how to apply it. any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually triggers when an object is undefined within an ejs template, which might be the reason in your case.

Try logging `data` in console. If `data` is `undefined` then `esc is not a function` error is obvious to occur as that means `data` is not available to your template and that is what you are trying to display. Resolve this issue by supplying proper data to the template.